# Comparing huge trees over slow network

Tags: algorithm, hash, tree, comparison

I have a tree like data structure:

- I have a list of work orders
- each work orders has several operations
- each operation has several roles
- each role has several resources nodes

Each work order, operation, role and resource node has a number of attributes.

I have two instances of such data strucutre: master and slave. I wish to periodically update slave and make it in sync with master. My question is: how do I do it really fast?

The problems are:

1. those two instances are huge
2. those two instances are on separate networks, connected by low throughput network
3. speed is critical parameter

**[edit]** 4. I do not have access to transaction log on master, just state of the master at this point in time (I have only read access on SQL views and that's it). **[/edit]**

What I was thinking was creating Merkle tree on both sides by hashing together node ID, node atributes and child nodes' hashes (bottom up, obviously).

And then comparing the trees by:

1. transmiting the list of top level hashes over the network
2. determining nodes which are not equal
3. recursively repeating the proces for mismatching nodes

Thus I get a list of nodes which are not in sync and then I update them.

The problem I see here is that I have to recreate both Merkle trees every time I compare instances, which costs time.

So, I was wondering if there is any other algorithm which I can try out?

Comment: Do you want to synchronize both (so writes are possible on master AND slave) or do you want to synchronize only the slave with the master?

Comment: I wish to sync slave with the master. So, it's a one way communication.

Comment: So why don't you just do the same operations on the master asynchronously on the slave (e.G. via RPC in another thread)?

Comment: Why not keep a local copy of the differences, if you can assume at some point in time they are synced, just track the incoming changes from that point, until you know they're synced again.  No reason for back and forth, just use the network to maintain changes to the remote.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut: because I do not have access to transaction logs on neither side. All I have is read access to SQL views on master and read/write access to SQL tables on slave. Yeah, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: @ChrisCM: Thanks, that is a good suggestion for minimising network traffic, yes. Thanks for that. Although, it still means I have to rebuild the hash tree every time to compare it to local copy of the old state, which is quite a big problem. Thanks for this suggestion anyway.

Comment: You could try a DBMS that has statement replication like MySQL.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut: nope, I'm integrating two complicated existing systems which cannot go offline, so changing DBMS is not an option.